# How can I set an offset on a centered react-leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I’m passing a bounds object to the bounds props on the Map Component (https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/v1/components.html#map).

I’d like that it uses the bounds to center and set the zoom (like it does by default) but with a offset (like for the tooltip) to allow some finetuning from the users part.

I’m getting the bounds from:

```
L.geoJson(currentZone.geoJson).getBounds();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a config object for `boundsOptions` to set `paddingTopLeft, paddingBottomRight or padding` in the form of an array.

**Leaflet doc:** https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#fitbounds-options

**React leaflet docs:** https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#map

```
 <Map
    ... attrs
    boundsOptions={{
      paddingBottomRight: [250, 0],
    }}
  >
```